# JVectormap - Different Border/Stroke width for State and Regions

Tags: jquery, css, javascript, jvectormap

I am using jVectorMap for displaying regions and States with geoJson data.
Basically it takes regions stroke width to show State borders.
I want different Border/Stroke width for regions and States.

Code snippet for setting Border style -

```
regionStyle: {
    initial: {
    fill: "white",
   "fill-opacity": 1,
    stroke: "red",
   "stroke-width": 0.2,
   "stroke-opacity": 1,
    }
},
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still having this problem. Did you ever find a solution?